Weird Selectable Area Next to Elements


#nameform, #emailform {
    width: 175px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
<input type="text" name="name" id="nameform" placeholder="First Name and Last Name">
<input type="email" name="email" id="emailform"placeholder="James@gmail.com">



I can't seem to figure out what causes some elements to have a weird selectable area next to them.
Screenshot 1: https://i.imgur.com/vfkWwKm.png
Screenshot 2: https://i.imgur.com/iKOQWZx.png
Thanks.
I tried fixing the problem from the CSS file. I'm not sure if that's where I should be looking at.
Edit 1: I added a snippet. Double click in between boxes.
Edit 2: The cause seems to be the structure of the HTML. Problem is, I'm a pixel-perfect freak. How can I arrange my HTML in such a way to be eye-pleasing but not create white space around elements?
Problem: https://i.imgur.com/4TBF0Cg.png
Solution (kind of): https://i.imgur.com/2um2mFZ.png
Is there a way to fix that in my CSS?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How to create "runnable" example.

Setting display: flex on the container of the two inputs fixes the problem. It also makes it easier to introduce space between them using the gap property (also set on the container). The space around can also be set as a padding on the container, much better for consistency.
